# get row of summary object

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to **get the numeric values for** the estimate and Std. Err for the summary object but I am accessing the rows wrong in apply (I think). How can I fix this?

```
require(MASS)
colnames(Cars93)
ll<-lm(Fuel.tank.capacity~Length*Passengers,data=Cars93)
s<-summary(ll)$coeff
apply(s,1,function(x){
  paste(x[1]+3,x[2]+3) #trying to return intercept and length for each row
  })
```

Goal:

```
-8.18 17.93
 0.11 0.09
.....
```

Comment: Are you looking for `sprintf()`? And eventually you want to remove the name-attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do what you're looking for:

```
t(apply(s,1,function(x){
  c(x[1],x[2])
}))


                     Estimate  Std. Error
(Intercept)       -8.180069747 17.93108069
Length             0.119717136  0.09943864
Passengers        -0.008363972  3.55247973
Length:Passengers  0.003146143  0.01941267
```

Answer (score 3):

The object 's' is a matrix

> is.matrix(s)

```
[1] TRUE
```

Therefore, you extract intercept and standard error from this object by:

```
s[,1:2]

                    Estimate  Std. Error
(Intercept)       -8.180069747 17.93108069
Length             0.119717136  0.09943864
Passengers        -0.008363972  3.55247973
Length:Passengers  0.003146143  0.01941267
```

Comment: I apologize, but my post was unclear. I added a comment in bold that will hopefully clarify it. I need to be able to perform operations on s based on which row it is in.

Answer (score 0):

The following code returns a list of (named) strings containing the Estimate, a space, and the intercept:

```
> apply(s[,c(1,2)],1,paste,collapse = " ")
                            (Intercept)                                  Length 
   "-8.18006974657324 17.9310806930227"  "0.119717136183204 0.0994386410426733" 
                             Passengers                       Length:Passengers 
"-0.00836397172098245 3.55247972849905" "0.00314614268107023 0.019412665227971"
```

This is not quite what you asked for, since it's still a named vector, but you can paste the remaining parts together using another `paste(collapse="\n")` as required.  Note that `\n` in a string is a carriage return but when displayed in the interpreter it just printed as \n.